# Перестал работать (ранее работавший код) запускаемый из PyCarm - ругается прямо с первой строчки импорта

Tags: selenium-webdriver, pycharm

```
Windows 8.1
Python 3.8
PyCharm 2020.1
Chrome 81.0.4044.138
ChromeDriver именно под эту версию
Selenium 3.141.0
```

Был рабочий код который успешно запускался в этом окружении всю почти весь прошлый месяц
еще утром в понедельник всё тоже работало.

Внезапно во второй половине дня перестало запускаться ругаясь прямо с первых строчек:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python/new1.py", line 1, in 
    from selenium import webdriver
```

Удаление и питона и PyCarm с последующей их установкой не помогло.

Установка того же окружения на виртуальную машину с чистой 8.1 также не помогло.

При попытке запуска любого файла *.py (там разные вариации на одну и ту же тему работы с сайтом) в папке **pycache** появляется файл select.cpython-38.pyc даже если не открывать файл select.py и он успешно открывает бразуер. Если его удалить, то он при запуске любого файла снова появляется.

Answer (score 0):

Два дня мучений и виновник нашелся

Это файл с именем select.py - как только его либо переименовываешь, либо удаляешь из папки с питоновскими примерами, то остальные начинают запускаться нормально (как и раньше)